# bind root-component in a child-component in angular2

Tags: angular, web

I need to bind root component in a child component and when click appropriate link a popup will appear and display root component data [image]

added  inside activity.html page and called related functions 
but data not loading

```
<section id="ProjectContent" *ngIf="isShowPlan">
    <!--<project-app  [sectionType]="FLOWCHART" [pageType]="projectPageType"
    [section]="projectSection" [projectId]="newprojectId"  
    [clientId]="newclientId" [projectName]="projectName">
    Loading...</project-app>-->

    <project-app section_type="LINK" page_type="projectPageType"section="projectSection"
     project_id="newprojectId"client_id="newclientId" is_expand="true">
     Loading...</project-app>

     <!--<project-app sectionType="LINK" pageType="projectPageType" 
      section="projectSection" projectId="newprojectId" clientId="newclientId" 
      projectName="projectName">
     Loading...</project-app>-->

 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `DI` mechanism you can inject any Parent components to child

**Child.component.ts**:

```
...
constuctor(public parent: SomeParentComponent){

}
```

Comment: app Component is my root component, once i add the component there is no problem with setting input, problem is not loading the app component  in a modal

Comment: @christopher, You want load `app,component` into modal?